# python SPARQL query RESULTS BINDINGS: IF statement on BINDINGs value?

Tags: python, sparql

Using Python with SPARQLWrapper, JSON, urlib2 & cgi. Had trouble passing a working SPARQL query with some NULL values to python so I populated the blanks with a literal and will try to filter at the output. I have this results section example:

```
for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
          project = result["project"]["value"].encode('utf-8')
          filename = result["filename"]["value"].encode('utf-8')
          url = result["url"]["value"].encode('utf-8')
```

...and I print the `%s`. Is there a way to filter a value, i.e., IF VALUE NE "string" then PRINT? Or is there another workaround? I'm at the tail-end of a small project, I know I need a better wrapper, I just need to get these results filtered before I can move on. T very much IA...

Comment: Are those nulls values coming from OPTIONAL clauses in your SPARQL ?

Comment: Yes, nulls are coming from OPTIONAL in my SPARQL. Sorry for the delayed response, must not have gotten notification. I checked with SPARQLWrapper developers and received a work around: 'for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    if result.has_key("party"):
        print "* " + result["person"]["value"] + " ** " + result["party"]["value"]
    else:
        print result["person"]["value"]'. I'll need to finesse this somehow to use %s...Were you going to suggest a different solution?

Comment: no, not really. It seems like the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the developers of the SPARQLWrapper library, and the question had been [already answered at the mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=92FA9430-06D7-44E6-9DD3-675460C81B2B@riotsystems.com&forum_name=sparql-wrapper-devel).

Regarding optionals values on the original query, the result set will come with no values for those variables. The problems is that we'd need to parse the query to populate such missing entries, and we want to avoid such parsing; therefore you'd need to check it for avoiding runtime problems with KeyError.

Usually I use a code like:

```
for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    party = result["party"]["value"] if ("party" in result) else None
```